# Passing RealmDB Results Object as Swift 2 Function Parameter

Tags: ios8, swift2, realm

I am working on a mobile app function using Swift 2 where I am trying to pass a RealmDB Results object as a parameter.

```
func myFunction(myDBresults: Results){
    Code to do stuff
}
```

Xcode give the error with a little upward arrow pointing at the R in "Results":

**Reference to generic type 'Results' requires arguments in <...>**

I don't know what is being required here as I still learning about Swift. Could I get some pointers on what is being required here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Results is a generic type, so you have to either make the function generic or specify type of the object stored in the Results:

```
func myFunction(myDBresults: Results<MyObjectClass>) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Or, if you wish to have a function which can accept Results of any type:

```
func myFunction<T: Object>(myDBresults: Results<T>) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: I went with the first option and replaced the MyObjectClass with the Realm class type. It works as expected.

Comment: This part saved me "func myFunction<T: Object>"!! My use case was having a protocol function that returned Results<T>. Thank you!